# Android how to convert password protected Pdf file to image?

Tags: android, pdf

I am creating an application in which, a user can select an application from the sd card, and converting it to image and store in the sd card.
This is working fine when Pdf file is not a password protected.

But when selected file is password protected, then application gets a crash.
So how to prompt the user for entering the password and handle, or how to bypass entering a password.

Any solution will be very helpful.

Comment: Did you get fix for this

Comment: Yes, I fixed it by using itext library.

Comment: can anyone share the sample code ?